# Does improper Riemann integrable imply the set of all Riemann sums is bounded?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

> Say $f : (0, 1] \to \mathbb{R}$ is improper Riemann integrable on $[0,1]$.
>
> Show the set of Riemann sums $\{R(f,P) : P \in \mathbb{P}[0,1] \}$  is bounded  , where $R(f, P) := \sum_{i=1}^n f(t_i) (x_i - x_{i-1})$, $P = \{ 0 = x_0 < \cdots, < x_n = 1\}, t_i \in (x_{i-1}, x_i)$.

---

**Try**

For a sequence, it is direct that if $\langle a_n \rangle$ converges, then $\{a_n : n \in \mathbb{N} \}$ is bounded.

We have $f$ is Riemann integrable, $\lim_{||P|| \to 0} R(f, P) = \int_0^1 f$, where $||P|| := \max \{ x_i - x_{i-1} : i = 1,\cdots, n\}$.

Intuitively I can apply the fact in sequence to integral, but I'm stuck at how to show this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we take $$f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$$

$$P=\{0,1\}$$and
$$t=\frac{1}{n^2}$$

then
$$R(f,P)=n$$

what about when $n\to +\infty$.